# Conclude that if all but finitely many $s_n$ belong to $[a, b]$, lim $s_n$ belongs to $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Here's the question: Let $(s_n)$ be a convergent sequence. Conclude that if all but finitely many $s_n$ belong to $[a, b]$, lim $s_n$ belongs to $[a,b]$

Here's my attempt at a proof. Can someone please verify it or provide suggestions for improvement?

Suppose $(s_n)$ converges to $s \notin [a,b]$. Pick $\epsilon = $ min$\{|s-b|, |s-a|\}$.

Then, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n > N$, $|s_n - s| < \epsilon$

This implies that $\forall n > N$, $s_n \notin [a,b]$, contradicting the fact that there exist only finitely many $s_n$ such that $s_n \notin [a,b]$. Therefore, it must be the case that lim $s_n \in [a,b]$

Comment: Your proof is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

> *Claim* Suppose $x_n=0$ for all but finitely many $n$. Then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n=0$.

*Proof* ?

> *Corollary* Suppose $x_n=y_n$ for all but finitely many $n$, and (in fact one of) both sequences converge. Then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} y_n$.

*Proof* ?

> *Corollary* Suppose $a\leqslant y_n\leqslant b$ for all $n$. Then $a\leqslant \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} y_n\leqslant b$.

*Proof* ?